# Ficar atualizando o select na div da pagina sem refresh mysql php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma div que faço um select simples trazendo só a quantidade de registros do banco de dados, e jogo o resultado em um h3 dentro dessa div, só o que preciso é que essa div fique sendo atualizada automaticamente de 3 em 3 minutos,  mas não possuo tanto conhecimento para fazer isso, pois sou estudante ainda, quem puder me ajudar agradeço.

Meu codigo está assim:

```
<div class="w3-right">
          <?php
             include("connection.php");
             $query = "SELECT registroNovo FROM registros WHERE BLregistros=0 AND Usuario='$usuario'";
             $result_1 = mysqli_query($con, $query);
             $num_notificacoes = mysqli_num_rows($result_1);
           ?>
          <h3><?php if($num_notificacoes != 0){ echo $num_notificacoes;} else {echo '0';}?></h3>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode estar fazendo uso do AJAX para isso. Vou deixar um exemplo com o jQuery que é um framework javascript que facilita bem essa parte.

> MeuArquivo.php

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    $query = "SELECT registroNovo FROM registros WHERE BLregistros=0 AND Usuario='$usuario'";
    $result_1 = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $num_notificacoes = mysqli_num_rows($result_1);
    if($num_notificacoes != 0){
        echo $num_notificacoes;
    } else {
        echo '0';
    }
```

> MeuOutroArquivo.php

```
<div class="w3-right">
  <h3 class="notification-number">-</h3>
</div>

<script>
    var atualizaNotificacao = function (tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'MeuArquivo.php',
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function () {
                // loading..
                $('.notification-number').html('-');
            },
            success: function (resultado) {
                $('.notification-number').html(resultado);
                setTimeout(function() { atualizaNotificacao(tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos); }, tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos * 1000);
            },
            error: function () {
                $('.notification-number').html('error');
                setTimeout(function() { atualizaNotificacao(tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos); }, tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos * 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    // inicializando contador de tempo para atualizacao de 2 segundos...
    atualizaNotificacao(2);
</script>
```

> **ATENÇÃO:** Eu imagino que você possua o jQuery na sua aplicação, caso não possua inclua o script abaixo antes de iniciar a tag script do **MeuOutroArquivo.php**.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Olá, eu fiz desse jeito, mas ele fica mostrando sempre o valor 0, sendo que tem registro pra mostrar no banco de dados

Comment: Deu certo sim seu codigo, está dando problema com meu usuario, vou resolver aqui, mto obrigado msm por me ajudar!